# I am getting error while installing pytz on windows "

Tags: python, windows, pytz, zoneinfo

I am getting the following error while installing pytz for python on windows:

```
assert len(resources) > 10, 'zoneinfo files not found!' AssertionError: zoneinfo files not found!"
```

But I can see a folder named *zoneinfo* in pytz folder, which has files of all the countries.
Does anyone have an idea of what can be missing?

Comment: [edit] your question and include the full traceback. Describe step by step how are you installing `pytz`.

Answer (score 0):

run the

```
python setup.py install
```

from the pytz directory and not another directory.
It solved the issue for me.